# Discover clients connected to a network

Tags: networking, wifi

How can you discover who is connected to a wifi network near you? (you not being connected to it).

I know that some tools can scan your own network, and that some tools like Wireshark can monitor packages (and you can see the MAC addresses of these packages). But what I want to find is a tool that is command-line based for networks where I don't belong.

Is there any simple kismet or nmap command to output this information?

Comment: See my answer to that Q&A, it's not possible w/o joining the network to see clients of said network. The only other method would be to induce the clients into sending you a "hello" wifi packet by acting as an access point yourself. That is what Kismet is for.

Comment: If we capture passively the wifi packages and analyze them, would we be able to see where they are coming from and where they are going to? I suppose the MAC addresses have to be there.

Comment: I would expect you'd be able to see the MACS and he various handshaking that needs to occur, prior to a client joining an AP.

Answer (score 3):

*My answer to this SF Q&A, titled: [Find wifi enabled devices [stations] around](https://serverfault.com/questions/469093/find-wifi-enabled-devices-stations-around)*

You can use a tool such as kismet, http://www.kismetwireless.net/, to scan for wireless networks. I believe it can show you all wireless devices in your vicinity without having to have the devices being actively connected to same network.

[image: kismet example]

This post should give you a rough idea of how to accomplish the scanning of the network using Kismet. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/beacon-frames-80211-devices-and-kismet/3279.

Also as a side note you can use this tool, fing, http://www.overlooksoft.com/fing, to find out all the `MAC` addresses of the devices on your network.

```
% sudo fing 10.9.8.0/24
```

[image: fing example]