# How to set WiFi password on modem - buffalo airstation g54

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, modem

I borrowed a [WiFi modem from a friend - Buffalo Airstation G54](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_AirStation) [image].

I don't know about installations procedure, I just would like set a password to use the wifi, since now it is a free connection.
I don't have an installation cd, but I have found [a manual on the web](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/22774/Buffalo-Buffalo-Airstation-Wla-G54.html?page=6#manual).
I am on Linux - Ubuntu.
How can I set a WiFi password on this device?

#### EDIT #1

```
:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 70:5a:b6:3d:3f:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.28/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::725a:b6ff:fe3d:3fbf/64 scope link 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether f0:7b:cb:10:42:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Trying some of these addresses, the page is still not loaded.

#### EDIT #2

Since I don't know the right terminology, the following picture is representative of the connection that I am trying to set up:

[image]

**NOTE:** The Buffalo router would be the wireless router in the diagram above.

However, the Buffalo router doesn't seem to me to have a "WAN port", and the picture from the OP seems to support this: there is no "detached" port, and all the ports have the same shape.

I have tried:

```
:~$ sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-23 15:47 JST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0034s latency).
MAC Address: 00:60:B9:E3:04:E4 (NEC Infrontia)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.11
Host is up (0.088s latency).
MAC Address: E0:C9:7A:A2:E9:95 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.15
Host is up (0.074s latency).
MAC Address: BC:3B:AF:98:F5:F3 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.18
Host is up (0.096s latency).
MAC Address: 0C:30:21:2E:C9:56 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.28
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 5.44 seconds
```

And looked in the browser again for these 5 IPs, but the pages are not loaded.
Perhaps, is it a problem of the modem, instead of the WiFi router?

Comment: Did you try to access the router via network? If it's a free connection, you need to be able to do it. Just enter `192.168.2.1` (or whatever your ip address is, but replace the last number with a 1) in your browser while connected to the router

Comment: @msrd0, yes I have tried but it doesn't work: the page is not loaded.

Comment: What does `ip addr` return while connected to the router?

Comment: I added it into the edit. I tried many IP addresses and none of them work.

Comment: @Py-ser - just so it's clear. You connected your laptop/desktop to the airport via an Ethernet cable and then tried to connect to it using 192.168.11.1? I'd From the looks of it your `ip` info above tells me you might want to try 192.168.1.1 too.

Comment: From your edit I see you need to enter http://192.168.1.1

Answer (score 2):

To gain access to this device I'd try to connect to the Ethernet port on the back (the one in this picture) and then try to manually set my IP address per the instructions in the manual to 192.168.11.2. I'd then attempt to access via a web browser the IP 192.168.11.1.

[image: ss#1]

Assuming that doesn't work I'd also try to scan the network using either `fing` or `nmap`. For `fing` see my U&L Q&A titled: [Discover clients connected to a network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101089/discover-clients-connected-to-a-network/101093#101093).

For `nmap` you can scan your network using something like this:

```
$ sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

This will give you this type of output:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.181
Host is up (0.32s latency).
MAC Address: 00:18:51:43:84:87 (SWsoft)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.254
Host is up (0.014s latency).
MAC Address: 00:A0:CC:79:36:B3 (Lite-on Communications)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.20
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (29 hosts up) scanned in 27.39 seconds
```

From which you can then try to narrow down which IP belongs to the Airport.

Comment: @Py-ser - I'm just double checking before we go on a wild goose chase 8-). Have you tried `https://192.168.1.1` as well as `http://192.168.1.1`?

Comment: @I haven't, but unfortunately I can't right now. I will try it asap. What does the result of `nmap` say?

Comment: @Py-ser - the output you've provided tells me that there are 5 devices on your network that your system can reach via the network. It's got to be one of those IPs. If it is not, then the Buffalo device is configured in some other non-standard way that's going to be tricky for us to help you with.

Comment: Yes I can imagine it. But I thought that, having the device, with all the codes on its back, was still possible to recover its configuration... About the `nmap`, does that mean that 5 devices are connected to the wifi?

Comment: @Py-ser - you're not guaranteed to get its configuration, only you can restore it to factory defaults if you have to (BTW, I'm not recommending that just stating it). The 5 IPs are 5 devices that are connected to this device, assuming it's acting as your DHCP server. You can partially confirm this by not connecting it to the cable modem.

Comment: I mean, if owning the hardware does not allow me to restore the right procedure, then anyone can change its configuration and set a password instead of me, and I don't think this is possible, right?

Comment: @Py-ser - most consumer hardware such as this type has the ability to restore to factory defaults with physical access to the hardware. It' not a simple procedure but is fairly doable esp. w/ access to the user's manual.

Comment: so you are suggesting to restore defaults?

Comment: @Py-ser - that would be my next option after exhausting every other option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [page 10](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/22774/Buffalo-Buffalo-Airstation-Wla-G54.html?page=10#manual) of the manual you linked. It states that the IP address is 192.169.11.1. If you plug that into your browser and use the default password and username, you should be able to log in.

Comment: I'm sure you can edit the IP address of the router

Comment: Page 9 of [this manual](http://www.danets.com/download/WHR-HP-G54-Manual.pdf) even says: `Enter 192.168.11.1 into the URL field. Naturally, if you change your AirStation’s IP address, you’ll have to enter the new address instead.`

Comment: Yeah he probs just needed the default. Your `ip addr` recommendation is good if that does not work.

Comment: If you don’t know the IP address, you can scan the whole address range of your local network using nmap. The class C networks are pretty small, it will be fast.

Comment: @palec, it could be the right thing here. How does it work?

Comment: @CameronNemo, ofc it was the first thing I tried.

Comment: @Py-ser The answer provided by slm already covers my idea.